# C# Get information from a listbox object

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a class called chamberlist which has only a list in it with chambers.
From a text document I am loading the credentials in a chamber object.

In my listbox I've set my datasource from the chamberlist so every chamber added to the chamberlist his list will be added to that listbox.

My question is how can I get the selected item from that listbox and do something with it, like put the chambernumber in label1 and the maxamount of people in label2.

Here are my classes:

ChamberList:

```
class ChamberList
{
    public static List<Chamber> chambers = new List<Chamber>();
    private static ChamberList instance = null;

    public ChamberList()
    {

    }

    public List<Chamber> readAllChambers()
    {
        
        return chambers;
    }

    public void addChamber(Chamber  c)
    {
        chambers.Add(c);
    }

    public static List<Chamber> getChambers()
    {
        return chambers;
    }
    public static void setChambers(List<Chamber> chambers)
    {
        ChamberList.chambers = chambers;
    }

    public static ChamberList getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new ChamberList();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Chamber:

```
class Chamber
{
    private int chambernumber;
    private int maxGuests;
    private Boolean isBooked;
    public static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

    public Chamber(int chambernumber, int max, Boolean booked)
    {
        this.chambernumber = chambernumber;
        this.maxGuests = max;
        this.isBooked = booked;
    }

    public int getChamberNumber()
    {
        return chambernumber;
    }
    public void setChamberNumber(int chambernum)
    {
        this.chambernumber = chambernum;
    }
    public int getMaxGuests()
    {
        return maxGuests;
    }
    public void setMaxGuests(int max)
    {
        this.maxGuests = max;
    }
    public Boolean getIsBooked()
    {
        return isBooked;
    }
    public void setIsBooked(Boolean b)
    {
        this.isBooked = b;
    }
    public static List<Person> getPersons()
    {
        return persons;
    }
    public static void setPersons(List<Person> persons)
    {
        Chamber.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAOChamber dc = new DAOChamber();
        dc.loadAllChambers();
        listBox1.DataSource = ChamberList.getInstance().readAllChambers();
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "chambernumber";
        
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

This is what I've got so far, but I want instead of "hotelsysteem.chamber" the chamber number to be displayed and the labels filled with the information of the selected chamber.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto added it to the post!

Answer (score 0):

Cast the SelectedItem properly and then use the object as shown below. I have not tested it, but it should work theoretically.

```
Chamber c = listBox1.SelectedItem as Chamber;
label1.Text = c.chambernumber.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Chamber` class looks a lot like if you came from another (perhaps Java?) language. That's not how you write normal models in c#, it should be more like this, using *properties*;

```
public class Chamber
{
    public int ChamberNumber { get; set; }
    public int MaxGuests { get; set; } 
    public bool Isbooked { get; set; }

    public static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

    public Chamber(int chambernumber, int max, Boolean booked)
    {
        ChamberNumber = chambernumber;
        MaxGuests = max;
        IsBooked = booked;
    }
}
```

With this, you also allow yourself to use the values to bind to the `ListBox`:

```
DAOChamber dc = new DAOChamber();
dc.loadAllChambers();
listBox1.DataSource = ChamberList.getInstance().readAllChambers();
listBox1.DisplayMember = "ChamberNumber";
```

Then, you can get the selected item with the `SelectedValueChanged` and use:

```
Chamber chamber = listBox1.SelectedValue as Chamber;
label1.Text = chamber.ChamberNumber.ToString();
label2.Text = chamber.MaxGuests.ToString();
// etc
```

Comment: you are right ive always used java and just started c#, but thanks a lot for the answer!